# Elements inside the row to be center aligned

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want is that these circles to be center aligned , I tried using some display inline block but no affect on it and some other properties that make center align but i failed [picture of those circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aegbt.png)
I am searching for this already the whole day :s

How can help me on this one?
Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

```css
.menu{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:green;
    line-height:100px;
    background:#32C947;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu:hover{
    color:#ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#333
}
```

```html
 

<div class = "container">
  <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
          <h1 class = "_font ">All Plans Include</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 ">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Hello</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 ">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 ">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 ">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 ">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 ">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 ">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 ">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>   
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what `bootstrap` are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.menu{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:green;
    line-height:100px;
    background:#32C947;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}

.menu:hover{
    color:#ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#333
}
```

```html
 

<div class = "container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12 center">
          <h1 class = "_font ">All Plans Include</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 center">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Hello</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 center">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 center">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 center">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 center">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 center">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 center">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 center">
          <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
          <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
        </div>   
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To the parent `div` of a circle you have to give some `width` property and use 
this and `margin: 0 auto;`. I hope this will works.

In your code parent `div .col-md-1` .so you have to create one more div and 
apply above property.

```
<div class="col-md-1 ">
   <div class="circle_menu">
       <a href="#" class="menu"></a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="_circle">Google Analytic</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The col-md-1 class is probably from bootstrap and therefor floating to the left. You could add the col-md-offset class to push the menu items to the center.

Comment: You've probably used it on all items? The offset should, in your case, only be used on the first item (col-md-offset-2).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `Bootstrap` actually linked to your code?  I just put it into a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kotsenburg/pen/aypwMM)
and linked `Bootstrap3` and it formatted correctly as you want (except the text is to big). I took out these lines from your `.menu` class as well:

```
vertical-align: middle;
list-style-type: none;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

**Edit:**

So the reason why your circles are not centered is because you are using `Bootstrap`'s grid system.  The grid is sliced into 12 different sections and you have 8 of the sections filled with elements (and 12 isn't divided by 8 evenly).  That means that there are 4 spaces not being used to the right of your circles.

To fix this, I added two empty `div` tags before all of the elements you have implemented like so:

```
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
```

This makes it so that there are two empty grid slots before your circles (to the left) and two after (to the right).  Here is the [Updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kotsenburg/pen/aypwMM) for you to look at.

*Note*: I added this style for you to center your text through `CSS`:

```
div.row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: well basically i want is that they should appear in middle of the screen, all the circles to be in the middle

Comment: I see, hmmm, the `.container` class should use `margin: 0 auto;` which is meant to center elements so it should work like you have it. I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: @Umer I edited my answer for you.  This solution should solve your problem with the grid system.  Please note I did not do anything to the text as I thought that may be something you want to tweak yourself.  Hope I was of help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to center align that block. But since you use the Bootstrap it will be best to use the in build display:block property of a center-block class.

> Set an element to display: block and center via margin. Available as a
>   mixin and class.

*Read More from Here [Bootstrap Documentation About centering a Class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center)*

You can do either any one of this

```
 <div class = "container center-block">
 <div class="row ">
  CODE SNIPPPET
 </div>
 </div>
```

OR

```
<div class = "container">
     <div class="row center-block">
      CODE SNIPPPET
     </div>
     </div>
```

The `center-block` class which we add overrides the `display:block` put in by using the regular `container` or `row` class

Hope This helped. Happy Coding. :)

Comment: well i appreciate your help, I tried it but im not able bring the circles in middle of the screen

Comment: I tried that part in my websites and it worked fine. Could you post some screenshots. :)

Comment: [This a full code](https://ibb.co/hybqCF
https://ibb.co/iUQ6ma
https://ibb.co/k0YgKv)

Comment: i used two 2 blank columns before and after these circles . that worked but changing screen size make the problem .  , text don't appear to move along the circles.[look at this](https://ibb.co/b8ovCF)

Comment: well its solved by applying 2 blank columns and previous css file. :)